# VBA Run-time error 13

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have created a simple code however it keeps coming up with run time error 13. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
Dim x As Integer
x = ActiveSheet.Range("ALL_PROJECTS").row
Rows("x:1048576").EntireRow.Delete
Range("A3").ClearContents
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a variable so you need to concatenate it into the rows statement, or you are using the literal text "x":

```
Rows(x & ":1048576").EntireRow.Delete
```